# Select rows from dataframe based on a unique values of other column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, data-transform

One of the column of my dataframe has values shown as below:

```
air_voice_no_null.loc[:,"host_has_profile_pic"].value_counts(normalize = True)*100

1.0    99.694276
0.0     0.305724
Name: host_has_profile_pic, dtype: float64
```

that's 99:1 for each unique value in that column.

I now want to make a new a dataframe, such that it has 60% of 1.0 and 40% of 0.0 from that dataframe along with all rows(of course with less number of rows).

I've tried splitting it using `strat` function of `train_test_split` class of `sklearn.model_selection` as shown below, but with no luck getting dataframes with equal proportions of each unique value.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

profile_train_x, profile_test_x, profile_train_y, profile_test_y = train_test_split(air_voice_no_null.loc[:,['log_price', 'accommodates', 'bathrooms','host_response_rate', 'number_of_reviews', 'review_scores_rating','bedrooms', 'beds', 'cleaning_fee', 'instant_bookable']],
                                                                                   air_voice_no_null.loc[:,"host_has_profile_pic"],
                                                                                   random_state=42, stratify=air_voice_no_null.loc[:,"host_has_profile_pic"])
```

and this is what the above code resulted in, with no change in number of rows.

```
print(profile_train_x.shape)
print(profile_test_x.shape)
print(profile_train_y.shape)
print(profile_test_y.shape)

(55442, 10)
(18481, 10)
(55442,)
(18481,)
```

How do I select subset of my dataset with a decreased number of rows, while maintaining appropriate proportions of each class of the `host_has_profile_pic` variable.

link to the complete dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/stevezhenghp/airbnb-price-prediction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following way:

```
import pandas as pd

# create some data
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0] * 10 + [1] * 90})

print('original proportion:')
print(df['a'].value_counts(normalize=True))

# take samples for every unique value separately
df_new = pd.concat([
    df[df['a'] == 0].sample(frac=.4),
    df[df['a'] == 1].sample(frac=.07)])

print('\nsample proportion:')
print(df_new['a'].value_counts(normalize=True))
```

Output:

```
original proportion:
1    0.9
0    0.1
Name: a, dtype: float64

sample proportion:
1    0.6
0    0.4
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to play with `frac` inside of `sample` to get fair proportions of my very highly unbalanced dataset. Also, I couldn't find how that `frac` works and documentation didn't have any information on same. It would be really helpful for me if you could provide me with any resources to learn how `frac` works.

Comment: Or, tell me how could I adjust `frac`, so I could know that how many rows of each class my new dataframe is gonna get.

Comment: @Sharmas `frac` is a fraction. No magic behind it. Suppose, you have `X` rows with `1`s and `Y` rows with `0`s. Then after sampling you gonna have `X * frac_x` and `Y * frac_y` respectively. You may use `n` instead of `frac` to determine exact number of rows to be in the samples. For example, `n_x` and `n_y` may both be `min(X, Y)` to get equal number of `0`s and `1`s in the sample. Pretty simple math easy to be tuned and implemented with python and pandas.